# Better way to overload constructor in python?

Tags: python

So I am aware that class methods can be used to "overload" the init method in python, but I'm running into a bit of a problem. Say, for example, I have a constructor like this:

```
def __init__(self, serviceName, endpoint, exportedInterface, exportedObject, remoteObjectInterface, remoteObjectProxy,
                interruptionHandler, invalidationHandler):

    self._serviceName = serviceName;
    #etc.

@classmethod
def createConnection(cls, serviceName):
    return cls(serviceName, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
```

Do I really have to list out a value for every single data member in the class method, just to create an instance of the class with a class method? Also, I plan to add more data members to the class later on, but I'm not to happy about having this unwieldy init function with like 15 arguments. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use default values for the parameters. Then you can specify which one you want to replace.

```
def __init__(self, serviceName, endpoint = None, exportedInterface = None, 
             exportedObject = None, remoteObjectInterface = None, remoteObjectProxy = None,
             interruptionHandler = None, invalidationHandler = None):

    self._serviceName = serviceName;
    #etc.

@classmethod
def createConnection(cls, serviceName):
    return cls(serviceName)
```

Now you can set only some arguments like this (the other will use their default values):

```
@classmethod
def createConnectionWithInterruptionHandler(cls, serviceName, interruptionHandler):
    return cls(serviceName, interruptionHandler=interruptionHandler)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Two options are:

Use keyword arguments. e.g.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for names in ("serviceName", ...):
        setattr(self, "_" + name, kwargs.get(names, None))
```

Make `__init__` do the bare minimum and use factory functions to do the appropriate initialization

```
def __init__(self): pass

@classmethod
def createConnection(cls, serviceName):
    foo = cls()
    foo._serviceName = serviceName
    return foo
```

Comment: why are you using `__setitem__` directly instead of `self["_"+name] = kwargs.get(names)`? Or do you maybe mean to use `setattr` instead?

Comment: @Tadhg: Yes, I meant `setattr`